# Calculate difference of elements in array

Tags: c#, arrays, linq, c#-4.0

Is there a way to calculate the difference between elements in an array and check if difference is > 1 using LINQ?

So if you have an array {1,2,3,5,8,9}, want to know what the difference is between each of the elements and only get the elements that follow each up directly, so difference == 1.

Is this possible using LINQ?

Comment: should 8,9 in you're example be included?

Comment: What should { 1, 2, 3 } return? And { 1, 2, 2, 3 } ? For example the first could return { 1, 2, 3 } OR { 2, 3 } OR { 1, 2, 2, 3 }. The second { 1, 2, 2, 3 } OR { 2, 3 }...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the `.Where` overload that uses the index - of course this also uses the fact that numbers is an array with an index operator:

```
int[] numbers = new[] { 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 9 };
int[] followNumbers = numbers.Where((x, idx) => 
                                (idx >=1 && numbers[idx-1] == x-1 
                                 || (idx < numbers.Length-1 
                                     && numbers[idx+1] == x+1) ))
                              .ToArray();
```

Edited to capture all numbers that are part of an "island" of consecutive numbers, with an island size of > 1 - that means you have to look forward and backward from each number to find if either the predecessor or successor is consecutive.

Output is `{1,2,3,8,9}` in the example case.

Comment: this looks good, I only want the output array to contain the numbers that follow each other consecutively...

Comment: @Tony: So this solution works for you, or you expected a different outcome?

Comment: @Tony: Sorry had a `<=` where it should have been a `<` - should work fine now

Answer (score 3):

You can use some tricks with [`Enumerable.Zip`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267698.aspx)

```
var testArray = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 9 };
var withNextElement = testArray.Zip(testArray.Skip(1), Tuple.Create);
var onlyOffByOne = withNextElement.Where(x => x.Item1 + 1 == x.Item2);
var withMatchingNext = onlyOffByOne.Select(x => x.Item1);
foreach(var item in withMatchingNext)
    Console.WriteLine(item);
```

gives

```
1
2
8
```

How do you want to handle the last element?

Should 9 be included? Should the last element in `{1,2,3,5,8}` be included?

Comment: I only want the elements that follow each other consecutively

Answer (score 2):

```
    int[] a = { 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 9 };
    var b = a.Where((item, index) =>
    {
        if(index + 1 == a.Length)
            return false;

        return item - a[index + 1] == -1;
    }).ToArray();
```

Comment: That will never include the last one

Comment: b = {1, 2, 8}; // So, yes, last one will be included.